# How can I demonstrate cache misses?

Tags: c, performance, caching

Inspired by [Meyers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE&t=1h) I am reading on [computer cache](http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/) and wanted to make an experiment, that demonstrates the mentioned things. Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef uint8_t data_t;

    const uint64_t max = (uint64_t)1<<30;
    const unsigned cycles = 1000;
    const uint64_t step = 63;  // tried also for 64

    volatile data_t acu = 0;
    volatile data_t *arr = malloc(sizeof(data_t) * max);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        arr[i] = ~i;

    for(unsigned c = 0; c < cycles; ++c)
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < max; i += step)
            acu += arr[i];

    printf("%lu\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Anbd then just `gcc --std=c99 -O0 test.c && time ./a.out`. I ahve checked, and my CPU's cache lines are 64 bytes long. By assigning `step = 64` I tried to generate cache misses much more often, than with `step=63`.

However, the `step=63` actually runs marginally faster. I suspect I am a "victim" of prefetching, because my RAM reads are sequential.

*How can I improve my example of walking an array, to demonstrate the cost of cache misses?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `step = 63` you will still get a lot of cache misses. The first two accesses will be on the same cache line, but the next 63 will cause a cache misses, accessing the 63th, 6th, 61th, ... byte of the line. A better way to measure it would be to show the difference between `step = 1`(almost no cache misses) and `step = 64` (always a cache miss) and adjust `max` to have the number of accesses in total.

Comment: Indeed, with `63` the OP should observe only 1/64 less cache hits than with `step=64`, i.e. max. 1.5% difference in runtime, which is then again (partly) compensated by the bigger number of loops.

Comment: `user 0m37.230s` versus `user 0m51.152s`. There are still many things I don't understand, but the experiment is successful. Wohoo!